# Correct script loading order using bootstrap4 (Knockout, Jquery)

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have that script order(it works, but regarding bootstrap4 everything should be at the end of the body-tag):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"> </script>
</head>
```

When using this:

```
<head>

</head>
<body>
...content...



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"> </script>
</body>
```

I get "Ko is not defined". What to to here ?

Comment: Do you put that in $( document ).ready()?

Comment: Sounds like it's probably your script that's causing that error, as part of your `...content...` - you should also include _your_ scripts after those, at the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: When putting `ko.applybinding` into the document ready handler i get "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" ...